# Effective density of states $N_c$ at different temperature for $\rm Si$

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronics, electronic-band-theory, density-of-states

For Silicon at room temperature, Nc = 2.8x10^19 per unit volume. For 300K, m*/m = 1.81 for Silicon. Now Nc is proportional to 1.5th power of both temperature and m* (effective mass). So, at any other temperature, what should be the effective mass of electron to be taken? Or will it be same for all the temperature?

Comment: What does a changing density of states mean in terms of the band structure? How does the effective mass relate to the band structure?

Comment: Where did you get that value for the effective mass? The effective mass in the conduction band of silicon at $300\ {\rm K}$ is around $m^*/m_e=1.09$.